# Scala; Expression of type (X)=>X doesn't conform to type SupX

Tags: scala, scala-swing

I'm a scala newbie who play with scala-swing. And want to translate a given `scala.swing.Point` on a `scala.swing.event.MousEvent` :

I would like to send mouse event to a class responsible to handle shapes selections. But because a shape has a location relative to his container (*sheet*) but MouseEvent.point is relative to the window I should translate/relativize it before.

So, I have a `Selection` class who receive `MouseEvent`s :

```
case class Selection(sheet:Sheet) {

  def on(event:Event) = event match {
    case clicked:MouseClicked => {
      clicked.modifiers match {
        case scala.swing.event.Key.Modifier.Control => 
          sheet.getItemAt(clicked.point).map(addToSelection)
        case _ => 
          sheet.getItemAt(clicked.point).map(setSelection)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a `Sheet` who his the shapes container (and know how to translate points).

```
class Sheet extends Component {
  private val selection = Selection(this)

  listenTo(mouse.clicks, mouse.moves)
  reactions += {
    case e:MousePressed => selection.on(translate(e))
    case e:MouseClicked => selection.on(translate(e))
  }

  /** Here is my problem :
   * > Expression of type (MouseEvent) => MousePressed doesn't conform to expected type Event
   */
  def translate(original: MouseEvent): Event = original match {
    case pressed:MousePressed =>
      pressed.copy(point=relativize(pressed.point))
    case clicked:MouseClicked =>
      clicked.copy(point=relativize(pressed.point))
    case other:MouseEvent=>
      other
  }  
}
```

I can bypass this problem with an ugly cast :

```
case pressed:MousePressed =>
      pressed.copy(point=relativize(pressed.point)).asInstanceOf[MousePressed]
```

But then I have another more strange compiler problem :

> Error:(32, 21) missing arguments for method copy in class MousePressed; 
>   follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
>
> pressed.copy(point = relativize(pressed.point)).asInstanceOf[MousePressed]

And here, I'm lost and need your help to do this simple conversion.

Of course all methods use `scala.swing._` types (and never mixes between scala.swing.*`and`java.awt.*`)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the compiler problem, you can understand what's complaining about looking at the [MouseEvent](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.swing.event.MouseEvent) (and specifically [MousePressed](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.swing.event.MousePressed)) documentation.

The case class is defined with two parameter lists, with the following simplified signature

```
MousePressed(source: Component, point: java.awt.Point, modifiers: Modifiers, clicks: Int, triggersPopup: Boolean)(peer: java.awt.event.MouseEvent) extends MouseButtonEvent
```

As you can see there's a second parameter list expecting the `peer` object, which is the underlying java swing object. You can access the `peer` instance using the attribute of the same name (e.g. `pressed.peer`)

The `copy` method, generated by the case class definition, probably expects this second parameter, like this

```
pressed.copy(point = relativize(pressed.point))(pressed.peer)
```

With the second parameter list missing, the compiler is inferring that you want to partially apply the `copy` method, thus it suggests you to use the

```
pressed.copy(point = relativize(pressed.point) _
```

syntax for [partially applying](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala) the curried function

Comment: Thanks a lot. And it remove the need of casting (who was required by my Ide who had troubles to parse this wrong expression)